# Ruby reverse string with unshift

Tags: ruby

To learn LIFO FIFO, I'm trying to make a method that reverses a string

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
def reverse(string)
    reverse = []

    string.split.each do | char | 
        reverse.unshift(char)
    end

    puts reverse.join
end

reverse("Hello")
```

When I do this though, console just returns "Hello". Shouldn't unshift return "olleH"?

i.e for each character, it goes in order and adds to the beginning of the reverse array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split` isn't doing what you think it is (by default, it splits on whitespace, not on each character):

```
> "Hello".split
#=> ["Hello"]
```

You probably want `chars`:

```
> "Hello".chars
#=> ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
```

You can also just use the `each_char` method:

```
string.each_char do |char|
```

Answer (score 2):

`split` splits on whitespace by default and because of that, only a single token, `Hello`, is yielded. Try with `Hello world` and you'll get `world Hello`.

The solution is to pass a delimiter, in this case an empty string, `""`, to the `split` method.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `string.split` is not splitting the array into individual characters. Change it to `string.split('')`:

```
def reverse(string)
  reverse = []

  string.split('').each do | char | 
    reverse.unshift(char)
  end

  puts reverse.join
end

reverse("Hello")
# => olleH
```